# Google maps javascript api working slow

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am working on an app with maps on each pages.
Problem is that google maps javascript api slows down app very, very much... and also take much time to load and sometimes it even not load in slow network.
Can anyone recommend other maps engine that is much faster than google maps

Comment: Use leaflet (http://leafletjs.com/). A map library optimized for mobile

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the map asynchronously? Doing that may speed up your application dramatically. [Asynchronously Loading the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)